# How to access private members of an Objective-C class from a Swift extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift, language-interoperability

I'm trying to extend an Objective-C class in Swift and make it conform to the `Equatable` protocol. This requires to access some *private* members of the extended class, which the compiler doesn't let me do. What is the correct way to do it without making the private members public?

My Swift code:

```
import Foundation

extension ShortDate : Equatable {  }

public func == (lhs: ShortDate, rhs: ShortDate) -> Bool {
    if (lhs.components.year == rhs.components.year)
        && (lhs.components.month == rhs.components.month)
        && (lhs.components.day == rhs.components.day) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface ShortDate : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding> {
    NSDate           *inner;
    NSDateComponents *components; // The date split into components.
}

...

@end
```

The error I'm getting:

> ShortDate.swift:26:9: 'ShortDate' does not have a member named 'components'

Comment: Did you add proper header to Swift header: `YourAppName-Bridging-Header.h`?

Comment: Yes, sure, the bridging header is in place and I can use the ShortDate class in my Swift code. I simply want to add comparison using operators instead of member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that there is no way to access Objective-C instance variables from Swift. Only Objective-C properties get mapped to Swift properties.

Comment: Looks like that. I solved it with properties instead.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this question while trying to find a way to access a private variable of a class from one of the SDKs we use. Since we don't have or control the source code we can't change the variables to properties. I did find that the following solution works for this case:

```
extension ObjcClass {
    func getPrivateVariable() -> String? {
        return value(forKey: "privateVariable") as? String
    }

    open override func value(forUndefinedKey key: String) -> Any? {
        if key == "privateVariable" {
            return nil
        }
        return super.value(forUndefinedKey: key)
    }
}
```

Overriding `value(forUndefinedKey:)` is optional. `value(forKey:)` will crash if the private variable doesn't exist on the class unless you override `value(forUndefinedKey:)` and provide a default value.